# IMport CSV file to Mysql using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Whether can we select path in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` using VB.net.

```
Query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'path1' INTO TABLE student.meter FIELDS
TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

In Path1 ---- I have to select the path from textbox.

Comment: didn't you try that?

Comment: I tried  like this ' + path1 + ', but its showing error

Comment: Query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  " + path1 + " INTO TABLE student.meter FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"         , Sql syntax error

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? I am asking this for the third time :)

Comment: you have an error in you SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c:/3.csv

Comment: copy and paste in mysql and see if it is working fine?